# How to draw lines in the same order as in the image below in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

If I onHover No.1(text), I want to implement an animation that is drawn in order from No. 2 onwards.

[image]

**This is my source code.**

```
<span ohMouseOver={() => setMenu("design"} className="design">
 ARCHITECTRURE DESIGN
</span
```

What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use an SVG `<path>` and animate `stroke-dasharray`/`stroke-dashoffset` on hover

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}

a svg {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

a path {
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
}

a:hover path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>spacer</p>

<a href="#">
hover over me
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 70">
  <path fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="M10,65h50v-50h50"/>
</svg>
</a>
```